# Enforce tick for first and last value for XValueAxis of ReportLab

Tags: python, reportlab

For a chart plotted by ReportLab, how can I enforce a tick for the first and the last value of an `XValueAxis`?

For `NormalDateXValueAxis` there are `forceFirstDate` and `forceEndDate`, but I did not find anything like this on `XValueAxis`.